# How to make table view animations smooth when resizing a cell

Tags: ios, uikit

I have a UITable view with custom cells. Some cells have a button to expand/collapse. Sometimes the cell being resized appears to jump in the UI.

I'm using Autolayout and dynamic height calculation via `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`. I have looked through several tutorials, including [this one on self-sizing table view cells](https://www.raywenderlich.com/8549-self-sizing-table-view-cells), which I'm using to investigate the issue.

To reproduce the issue, scroll midway through the table and expand several cells. Tap on a cell that's partially showing. The cell will appear to jump instead of staying in place.

Example:

[Video 1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11527iCWrzU-aU2GhWkPDA0tHIzWVzdrm)

The problem is more obvious when I comment out the line that scrolls to the top of the cell after selecting a cell.

[Video 2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EQv2HhaLVC6k7xlbUo_n9od3C8dxwL5e)

I tried @DonMag's suggestion. With small cells, the problem does not occur. When I increased cell heights to take up >60% of the screen height, the jump animation occurred ([video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10GM2LJidsbVuK_AkHRDgfxITXPvBDAiT)).

I changed

`Question Label.top = topMargin + 8`

to

`Question Label.top = topMargin + 800`

---

When I dive into the code, the problem seems to occur when calling

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

But this snippet is necessary for the table view to recalculate cell heights.

I want the cell to stay in-place while resizing, without the jumping animation.

Comment: There are various approaches to expand / collapse cells, so you may want to try looking at a few different ones. A frequent problem is when using multi-line labels... the text in a label is vertically-centered, so as the label expands the text "reveal" doesn't always look right. I recently put together a simple project similar to what you're trying to do. You can take a look at it here https://github.com/DonMag/ExpandCollapse and see if you can get some help from it.

Comment: Thanks, @DonMag. I've updated the description with some more info

Comment: If your cells / rows are going to be that tall, make sure you give the tableView an estimate, such as `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 880` (in `viewDidLoad()`. That should take care of the "jumping."

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, the issue is caused when the table has cells with varying heights (e.g. 100 vs 800). I can't use the same estimated height for every cell, or else the content appears to jump when expanding/collapsing cells.

The solution has 2 parts, both of which are needed.

**Using Real Cell Sizes**

In `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`, each row uses a precise calculation instead of an estimate.

**Multiple Reuse Pools**

I assigned a unique ID to every *type* of cell. Each *type* of cell has similar heights. For example, type A has height=120, type B has height=400.

Then I registered a different "pool" of cells for each type. Even though CustomCell is the the same class for different cell types, each cell type has different constraints and sizes. This allows a cell with the correct estimated size to be dequeued from the reuse pool.

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
[tableView registerClass:[CustomCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:typeA];
[tableView registerClass:[CustomCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:typeB];
...
NSString *cellID = // Could be typeA, typeB, etc.
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
```